# crystax ndk link error

Tags: android, android-ndk, linker, ndk-build

I'm trying to build [poco](https://pocoproject.org/) and [cegui](http://cegui.org.uk/) libs with crystax ndk(version 10.3.2) using cmake

```
export ANDROID_NDK=/.../crystax-ndk-10.3.2
cmake -DPOCO_STATIC=ON -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="../../AndroidBuildToolchain/android.toolchain.cmake" -DANDROID_ABI=x86  -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=21 -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=x86-4.9  ../..
```

and build my own app with android.mk and I got the same error(using ndk-build):

```
crystax-ndk-10.3.2/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lcrystax
```

And other link errors from, like these

```
error: undefined reference to 'sinf'
error: undefined reference to 'cosf'
error: undefined reference to '__getCurrentRuneLocale'
```

But when i'm trying to build the poco and my project with google NDK it works good. But I have reasons to use crystax. So, can anybody help me to find out the reason of these errors?

I've tried -lm flag for math(sin,cos) lib, but I had the same errors.